# avoid space between two field in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have three row in jasper sub report , I face problem when I got any one field value null or "" it will written either null or make space without writing anything which make report unwieldy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "blank when null" and "remove row when blank".

Comment: how can i remove row from ireport that I have seted when I run report ?

Comment: Couldn't you filter these out in the where clause of your query?  Something like this: Where fieldname <> '' and fieldname is not null